# Запись результата функции

Tags: php

Как записать результат функции в перменную?

mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `menu` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `href` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `pid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

INSERT INTO `menu` (`id`, `name`, `href`, `pid`) VALUES
(1, 'Hello ', 'hello', 0),
(2, 'hi', 'hi', 1),
(3, 'byy', 'byy', 0),
(4, 'quit', 'hello', 1),
(5, 'exit', 'exit', 2),
(8, 'qweqw', 'zxcvbnm', 2),
(9, 'qweqw', '2', 2);
```

php:

```
$parts_query = mysql_query("SELECT id, pid, name FROM menu");

if ($parts_query && mysql_num_rows($parts_query) > 0) {
    $parts_array  = array();
    $part_data[0] = 0;
    while ($part_data[0] = mysql_fetch_row($parts_query)) {
        $part_data[1] = isset($part_data[1]) && $part_data[1] > 0 ? $part_data[1] : 0;
        array_push($parts_array, $part_data[0]);
    }
    mysql_free_result($parts_query);
}

function menu($parts_array, $pid)
{
    $result     = "";
    $this_count = 0;
    foreach ($parts_array as $id => $element) {
        if ($element[1] == $pid) {
            $this_count++;
            if ($this_count == 1)
                $result .= ("<ul>
      ");
            $result .= ("<li><a href=\"./parts.php?id=" . $element[0] . "\">" . $element[2] . "</a>");
            menu($parts_array, $element[0]);
            $result .= ("</li>
      ");
        }
    }
    if ($this_count > 0)
        $result .= ("
</ul>");
    return $result;
}
$var = menu($parts_array, 0);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это вы хотите всё что в функции меню выводиться echo вернуть?

вообще, результат функции это то что в функции будет return $result;//или любая другая переменная. вам надо в функции вместо echo её аргумент писать в переменную:

К примеру:

**в начале функции:**

```
$result = "";
```

**вместо echo:**

```
$result .= "<li><a href=\"./parts.php?id=".$element[0]."\">".$element[2]."</a>";
```

**в конце функции**

```
return $result;
```

**а получить в переменную:**

```
$var = menu(...);
```

**при рекурсии как в Вашем случае вызов функции надо брать тоже с результатом:**

```
  $result .= menu($parts_array, $element[0]);
```

Comment: Если я так делаю, то получаетается так:
<ul>
 <li><a href="./parts.php?id=1">Hello </a></li>
 <li><a href="./parts.php?id=3">byy</a></li>   
</ul>
А должно быть так:
<ul>
   <li><a href="./parts.php?id=1">Hello </a><ul>
   <li><a href="./parts.php?id=2">hi</a><ul>
   <li><a href="./parts.php?id=5">exit</a></li>
   <li><a href="./parts.php?id=8">qweqw</a></li>
   <li><a href="./parts.php?id=9">qweqw</a></li>
   
</ul></li>
   <li><a href="./parts.php?id=4">quit</a></li>
   
</ul></li>
   <li><a href="./parts.php?id=3">byy</a></li>
   
</ul>
Как ты написал уже пробывал, поэтому и обратился сюда

Comment: Приведите в вопросе обновлённый код функции

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.

Comment: ААААА!!! ахтунг!!!  :-) вы меню то что впустую вызываете?
вместо menu($parts_array, $element[0]); надо $result .= menu($parts_array, $element[0]);